# How can I tell if at least one dataGridView row is selected c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a program that takes a value from the selected row in a dataGridView and passes it to a function. However, the gridView could be empty or could not have a row selected.
I took care of the empty Grid, but I was wondering if there is a way if I can tell if any row is selected.

I tried this:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows.Count) > 0)
{
    //It is not empty
}
int c = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count(); //this line gives me an error
if (c>0)
{
    //there is a row selected
}
```

Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out, the problem where the parenthesis after the second "Count" thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply remove the parenthesis after the "Count" keyword. It should look like this:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows.Count) > 0)
{
    //It is not empty
}
int c = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; //remove parenthesis here
if (c>0)
{
    //there is a row selected
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 && dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) {
     ......
}
```